# Read environment variables on Oracle 10gas

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, oc4j

When using OEM for 10gas, I can set some environment variables. How can I read these from my application? I've tried using JNDI, System.getenv() (throws an exception on Java 1.4), System.getProperty() .. No luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can set system properties as VM arguments ("-Dfoo=bar") and read them with System.getProperty("foo").  You put these in opmn.xml, or in the environment variable
OC4J_JVM_ARGS if using OC4J standalone.

Comment: I already got this working, but thought maybe there was a "better" way to set up variables (the Environment Variables list seemed likely to be used for my purpose). I have to hand over an EAR file to my customer and they will have to set a password variable after deployment. Would you say that system properties is the way to go? (I'm new with this old tech :) )

Comment: You can also define environment variables in opmn.xml.  Here is a good post on the subject: http://buttso.blogspot.com/2006/08/accessing-environment-variables-from.html